# Add a Logo to an Image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I'm using Matplotlib to create various graphs, and one of them is an image with a logo and text. It seems that every time that I plot the second image on top of the first, it rescale the whole plot.

I tried to use the extent argument but the whole plot uses the logo size to scale as shown in the image below.

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bkg = Image.open("C:/image/path")
logo = Image.open("C:/image/path")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9))

ax.imshow(bkg.resize((1600, 900)))

logo_x = 700
logo_y = 400

logo_width = 100
logo_height = 50
logo_image = logo_image.resize((logo_width, logo_height))

logo_extent = (logo_x,logo_x + logo_width,logo_y + logo_height,logo_y)

ax.annotate(text="This is a Text", xy=(100, 450), color="white", size="xx-large")

ax.imshow(logo, extent=logo_extent)

plt.axis("off")
```

[image]

The following image is a reference of what I'm trying to achieve. The logo has a transparent background.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The logo image become stretched covering all background, since
the **extent** parameter of the *ax.imshow* instruction scales according to the coordinate values relative to the entire plot, not just the background image.

To add the logo to bkg at the specified coordinates, you can instead use the ***paste()*** method from PIL...at least, it worked for me! =)

```py
from PIL import Image  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

bkg = Image.open("./back1.jpeg")  
logo = Image.open("./logo1.png") 

logo_x = 700  
logo_y = 400  
logo_width = 100  
logo_height = 50  

## Resize
bkg_resized = bkg.resize((1600, 900))  
logo_resized = logo.resize((logo_width, logo_height)).convert("RGBA")  

""" N.B. Converting to RGBA mode may be unnecessary, but it must be done when 
the image contains transparency info, such as an alpha channel, that should be preserved.
"""

# Paste the logo image onto the background image
bkg_resized.paste(logo_resized, (logo_x, logo_y), logo_resized)  

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9))  

# Display the background image with the logo image overlaid
ax.imshow(bkg_resized)  

ax.annotate(text="This is a Text", xy=(100, 450), color="white", size="xx-large")  

plt.axis("off")  
plt.show()
```